# ng if with a modulus operator in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

using ng-For and ng-If, I'm trying to display object of array to look like this [recovery code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyfSZ.png), and this is what i do [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/693g6.png),
 this is what im trying so far,

```
<div class="recovery-code" *ngFor="let x of recoveryCode?.recoveryCodes; let i = index;">
            <b>{{ x }}</b>
            <br *ngIf="i%5 === 0">
</div>
```

i also had problem to do space between array, had try `array.join(", ");` but didnt work, need advise how do i solve my problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `*ngFor` is on the wrong item. It's repeating the `div` instead of the content. Try this code below, it will work much better. It's also matching the recovery code look you are after.

`ng-container` is very helpful in solving this kind of problem because it's designed to leave no DOM trace behind itself. See https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

```
<div class="recovery-code">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let x of recoveryCode?.recoveryCodes; let i = index;">
        <br *ngIf="i > 0 && i%5 === 0" />
        <b>{{ x }}</b>&nbsp;
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Should output something similar to this:

```
11111 22222 33333 44444 55555
11111 22222 33333 44444 55555
11111 22222 33333 44444 55555
```